# Numpy / Pandas optimized vector operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, addition

Suppose I had a dataframe df:

```
  Vx    Vy
0 1.00  1.00
1 2.00  3.00
2 1.50  1.75
```

The goal is to create a new column `df['Vmagnitude']` defined as the magnitude of the vector sum between Vx and Vy, like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAXey.png):

```
  Vx    Vy    Vmagnitude
0 1.00  1.00  1.41421
1 2.00  3.00  3.60555
2 1.50  1.75  2.30489
```

What would be the fastest and/or most pythonic way of implementing this using numpy/pandas?

Comment: `np.sqrt(df.Vx.pow(2) + df.Vy.pow(2))` or `np.sqrt(df.pow(2).sum(1))` if this is the entire frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the problem gets large you can try using pandas eval. Make sure you install numexpr for the gains (`pip install numexpr`) , see [the numexpr readme here](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) to see how it works. If installed, Pandas just wraps this functionality into the `.eval` method.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame( random.random((5000000,2)), columns=('vx', 'vy'))

df.eval("vmag = sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)", engine='numexpr', inplace=True)
```

I think that's your best bet, numexpr makes use of multi-threading

```
In [24]: %timeit np.linalg.norm( df[["vx", "vy"]], axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 266 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit df.eval("sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)", engine='python')
10 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit df.eval("sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)", engine='numexpr')
10 loops, best of 3: 42 ms per loop
```

Also see [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/enhancingperf.html) for enhancing performance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [np.linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
df["Vmagnitude"] = np.linalg.norm(df[["Vx", "Vy"]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know numpy has magnitude built in

Answer (score 1):

A fast way (performance in 3D games e.g.) would be to not use the sqrt and store just the `x²+y² = x*x + y*y` in a column VMagnitudeSquare or however you like.
In most cases for further calculations you can just use that.

This all comes down to the sqrt function being "slow".
But that depends of your usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new column magnitude to be the sum of the square roots of the vectors as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 


d = {'Vx':[1,2,1.5], 'Vy':[1,3,1.75]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Magnitude'] = np.sqrt(df['Vx'].pow(2) + df['Vy'].pow(2))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Vx    Vy  Magnitude
0  1.0  1.00   1.414214
1  2.0  3.00   3.605551
2  1.5  1.75   2.304886
```